# how to create a datetime object in python 3x when seconds is a float

Tags: python, datetime

I need to create a datetime object with year, month, day, hour, min, sec and hundredths of seconds, preserving the fraction of a second information.

Can this be done?

This fails:

```
dto = dt.datetime(VLeaderData['Year'], month=VLeaderData['Month'],
    day=VLeaderData['Day'],hour=VLeaderData['Hour'],
    minute=VLeaderData['Minute'],
    second=(VLeaderData['Second']+VLeaderData['Hundredths']/100))
```

Because second needs to be an integer:
    TypeError: integer argument expected, got float

Have I exceeded datetime's capability here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to specify everything as integers ... If you have seconds as a float:

```
seconds = 30.1234
```

Then take the integer part for the seconds and calculate the number of microseconds:

```
secs = int(seconds)
microseconds = int((seconds - secs) * 100000)
```

Or, (if I'm understanding your code correctly) you have hundredths of a second as a field by itself:

```
microseconds = VLeaderData['Hundredths'] * 1000
```

and then pass it all to `datetime`:

```
datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, secs, microseconds)
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you haven't. You can pass the extra info to the `microsecond` parameter of your [`datatime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) object:

```
microseconds = VLeaderData['Hundredths']*1000
```

Comment: Many thanks folks, I had lost track of the hundredths argument